# How to find standard deviation in C++?

Tags: c++, statistics, standard-deviation

This is my first time trying to program something. I want to be able to input a variable amount of data and output the average and standard deviation. I want it to be as simple as possible and preferably using the commands that are already present in the current program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num[46];
    float amount_num;

    cout<< "How many numbers do you want? (max 45)\n";
    cin>> amount_num;

    for (int counter =0; counter < amount_num; counter++)
    {
        cout<< "Enter value "<< counter<< ":"<< endl;
        cin>> num[counter];
    }

    int total;
    int average;
    int latot;
    int fun;
    int n;
    int taco;
    int sd;
    int bell;

    for(int t= 0; t< amount_num; t++)

    {
        total = total + num[t];
    }

    average= total/amount_num;

    for(int t= 0; t< amount_num; t++)


    {
        latot =  num[t] - average;
        bell = pow (latot,2);
        fun = fun + bell;
    }

    n=amount_num-1;
    taco=fun/n;
    sd=sqrt(taco);

    cout<< "Average: "<< average<< endl;
    cout<< "SD: "<< sd<< endl;
}
```

Comment: What didn't work with this attempt? Did you get errors? Unexpected results/behaviour? Re: the code, I'm not a fan of the whitespace (I do one space either side of operators, e.g. `n = amount - 1;`), the naming (`latot` and `taco`?!), and the allocation of a big, unnecessary array. Good start, though; welcome to C++! :)

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the *sample* standard deviation. If you're not getting exactly the result you expect, then perhaps you wanted to calculate the *population* standard deviation instead?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of you code looks correct.  However, you should not use integer variables.  Instead, use floating point variables.  The use of integer variables is resulting in a lot of integer division which is causing a lot of numerical truncation errors.

For instance, with `average= total/amount_num` if `total` is 128 and `amount_num` is 10 then `average` will be 12 when it should be 12.8.  That truncation errors get propagated when computing the value deviants, `num[t] - average`.

A similar integer division problem is found with `taco=fun/n`.

Using floating point variables eliminates integer division and these intermediant numerical errors.

Comment: Why downvote? This is a good answer. You should not use int, use float or double instead!